# Script for creating users and set password on new servers

Tags: 20.04, bash, scripts

i want to create ubuntu user and set password automatically.
i want script to run command:

`useradd -s /usr/sbin/nologin username`

`passwd username`

and set password 1234

please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a command called [newusers](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/newusers.8.html) for this.

> The newusers command reads a file (or the standard input by default) and uses this information to update a set of existing users or to create new users. Each line is in the same format as the standard password file (see passwd(5)) with the exceptions explained below:

```
UserName:Password:UID:GID:comments:HomeDirectory:UserShell
```

An example (use `id` on commandline to list ids for the current user):

```
username:1234:1000:1000::/home/username:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

and you can do

```
sudo chmod 0600 file.txt
sudo newusers file.txt
```

to add those users into a system.

It is the preferred method for migrating users.

Comment: @Raffa "and set password 1234" is in the q ;=)

Comment: You know I didn't mean that one ;D